# Auto-populate a new row that includes a sequential number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a two part question.

1) I would like to create a table that auto-populates a new row that includes a sequential ID number (which includes text), whenever a previous row is filled out.  For example:
[image: Table Example]

In the example, "19-NBCC-0162" (in the "Tracking Number" column (column A) of row 510) is the ID number I would like to auto-populate when I enter data into the row above it (row 509).  I with thinking the new tracking number would appear when data is entered into the "Office" or "Date assigned" columns (C and F) of row 509.

2)The formula I have assigned to the "Tracking number" column cells, in order to include text with sequential number formatting, is:

`="19-NBCC" & TEXT(ROW(A161),"-0000")`

At the moment, I am not sure if this code would work when combined with the auto-population of a new row concept. If there is a better way to create sequential number formatting with text, I would love to know.
And if the two issues can work together, where the Tracking number is auto-populated even better!

Comment: I should mention that all the cells in rows 509, aside from the Tracking Number cell, have formulas that should also be included in the auto-populated row (row 510).

Comment: so basically, you have formulas in entire row?

Comment: is there something specific in A161? does this value change in every row?

Comment: ZygD, actually they are drop-down choices, linked to another worksheet.  But there is the possibility of including a column with a formula in the future.

Comment: ZygD, no, there is nothing specific about "A161".  161 just happens to be the last number in the list of current tracking numbers we have, so I altered the code - that was suggested on this site. 
[link(]https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automatically-number-rows-76ce49e3-d8d2-459b-bd85-ee1d3973e6e6) 
I'm not sure what "A161" actually represents. I thought it would be a cell reference, but it doesn't act that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood it correctly, in the bottom-most row you want to always have the next number populated, together with other empty cells (only having a dropdown lists each).

Dropdowns on cells can be achieved by copy pasting them down. No values selected, means they remain empty until someone  selects a value.

Now, your main formula in the "Tracking number" column. For example, if there is something written in the column "Office" previous row 509, we enter the number. Otherwise, leave it with empty string `""`.

```
=IF(F509<>"","19-NBCC" & TEXT(ROW(A161),"-0000"),"")
```

I would fill this formula in entire column.

Comment: Well, ZygD, that hit the spot!  Works like a charm!
Thank you, and you have increased my understanding of excel formulas.

Comment: I believe I just put you on the right path an you then fixed things yourself :) Because I have changed this formula a few times while it was already posted... Happy to help!

Comment: I know, I was trying your initial suggestion and altered it to what was your last suggestion, but noticed the formula kept changing.  LOL.  Thanks again.